# Generate all possible integer arrays

Tags: arrays, matlab, permutation

I would like to generate all possible integer arrays of a given length `L`, up to a maximum element size `M`.

The minimum element size is 1.

If `M = 3`, and `L = 2`, the output would be the following:

```
[1,1]
[1,2]
[1,3]
[2,1]
[2,2]
[2,3]
[3,1]
[3,2]
[3,3]
```

There are `M^L` different combinations, so I guess the Matlab code would look something like this:

```
function [arrays] = allArrays(M,L)
  for i = 1:(M^L)
    arrays(i) = % Something here that translates i to the desired array.
  end
end
```

I'm not sure what should go in the middle of the loop, any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You need all possible *permutations*, but the code for combinations is as simple as `combntns(1:3,2)`

Comment: @Asad: for which you need the mapping toolbox...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `ndgrid`:

```
[y x]=ndgrid(1:3,1:3);
resu=[y(:) x(:)];
```

If you want to give `M` and `L` as input, you should do the following trick:

```
arg=repmat((1:M)',1,L);
arg=mat2cell(arg,M,ones(1,L));
resu=cell(1,L);
[resu{:}]=ndgrid(arg{:});
resu=cell2mat(cellfun(@(x) x(:), resu,'UniformOutput',0));
```

result:

```
 resu =  
     1     1
     2     1
     3     1
     1     2
     2     2
     3     2
     1     3
     2     3
     3     3
```